# Php script missing sql query

Tags: php, mysql, sql

In my below php script that runs sql queries, it seems to run `$data` and `$stmt`
without any problem but for some reason `$stmt2` doesn't complete. I run this in powershell
and get no errors at all, but when I check MySQL workbench the data is all there except `ExtID` 
is null for all the new records, which is what `$stmt2` is supposed to affect.

Now, if I run that exact query in mysql workbench it works just fine and updates the records with the 
new `ExtID`, just not in the script. I'm wondering if it's simply how I've structured the statement.

Again, the first 2 queries work fine, and it's not triggering an error, it just simply doesn't update the ID and leaves it null. Since it works directly in mysql though, I'm hoping it's something I'm missing in syntax or structure.

here's the script:

```
            $data = mysqli_query($conn, " SELECT c.extension
                          , sum(Duration) AS Total_Talk_Time_seconds
                          , round(sum(Duration) / 60,2) AS Total_Talk_Time_minutes
                          , sum(if(LEGTYPE1 = 1,1,0)) AS Total_Outbound
                          , sum(if(LEGTYPE1 = 2,1,0) and ANSWERED = 1) AS Total_Inbound
                          , sum(if(Answered = 1,0,1)) AS Total_Missed
                          , SUM(IF(LEGTYPE1 = 1, 1, 0)) +                   -- outbound
                            SUM(IF(LEGTYPE1 = 2, 1, 0) AND ANSWERED = 1) +  -- inbound
                            SUM(IF(Answered = 1, 0, 1))  AS Total_Calls
                          , NOW() AS Time_of_report
                          , curdate() AS Date_of_report
                      FROM cdrdb.session a
                      INNER JOIN cdrdb.callsummary b
                           ON a.NOTABLECALLID = b.NOTABLECALLID
                      INNER join cdrdb.mxuser c
                           ON a.RESPONSIBLEUSEREXTENSIONID = c.EXTENSIONID
                      WHERE b.ts >= curdate()
                      AND c.extension IN (7276,7314,7295,7306,7357,7200,7218,7247,7331,7255,7330,7000,7215,7240,7358,7312)
                      group by c.extension")  or die(mysqli_error( $conn));


             $stmt = mysqli_prepare($conn2, "Insert into jfi.ambitionphone(Extension,       Total_Talk_Time_seconds, Total_Talk_Time_minutes, Total_Outbound, Total_Inbound,
             Missed_Calls, Total_Calls, Date_of_report,Time_of_report )
                VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)
                     ON duplicate key update
                         Total_Talk_Time_seconds = values(Total_Talk_Time_seconds),
                         Total_Talk_Time_minutes = values(Total_Talk_Time_minutes),
                         Total_Inbound = values(Total_Inbound),
                         Total_Outbound = values(Total_Outbound),
                         Missed_Calls = values(Missed_Calls),
                         Total_Calls = values(Total_Calls),
                         Time_of_report = NOW()
                         ") or die(mysqli_error( $conn2));

              $stmt2 = mysqli_prepare($conn2, "UPDATE jfi.ambitionphone a,
                                       (SELECT * FROM jackson_id.users where id in
                                       (48,75,76,77,81,82,83,85,86,87,99341,99344,99409,99422,99428)) j
                                       SET a.ExtID = j.id where a.extension = j.extension") or die(mysqli_error($conn2));
```

UPDATE:

This is the last portion of the script that I left out:

```
 $content = [];

 while ($d = mysqli_fetch_array($data, MYSQLI_ASSOC)) {

      mysqli_stmt_bind_param($stmt,"iidiiiiss", $d['extension'],
          $d['Total_Talk_Time_seconds'], $d['Total_Talk_Time_minutes'],
          $d['Total_Outbound'], $d['Total_Inbound'], $d['Total_Missed'], $d['Total_Calls'],
          $d['Time_of_report'], $d['Date_of_report']) ;
     mysqli_stmt_execute($stmt) or die(mysqli_error($conn2));

     // Store the current row
     $content[] = $d;

 }
```

Comment: You're just preparing the SQL query, you're not actually executing it...

Comment: Add `ini_set('display_errors', 1); ini_set('log_errors',1); error_reporting(E_ALL); mysqli_report(MYSQLI_REPORT_ERROR | MYSQLI_REPORT_STRICT);` to
the top of your script. This will force any `mysqli_` errors to
generate an Exception that you can see on the browser and other errors will also be visible on your browser.

Comment: @david thank you, I forgot to add the last portion of the script where my results get printed to JSON, but this is also where I execute $stmt. So could I just add a new execute after that while looop?

Comment: @TomN.: If that's where you want to execute it, sure.  The main point to take away from this is that if you want to execute your SQL code then you have to execute your SQL code.